# Plotting two spatial graphs in the same plot - R keeps cutting the graph

Tags: r, plot, spatial, par

I'm having a problem with my plots in R. Basically, I'm trying to plot two spatial graphs (MPC) (using `mfrow=c(1,2)`, but R keeps cutting the right edge of one of them.

I tried to change `oma`, `mai` and `mar` arguments of the `par` function, but it didn't work. If I plot them separately, this doesn't happen, which makes me think that the problem might be in the `par()` function.

Here's part of the script I'm using.

```
#first plot
par(bty="l", mfrow=c(1,2), mar=c(0,1,0,1), mai=c(1,1,1,2), lty="solid", lwd=3, pty="m")
plot(area.total.mari.mpc)
par(lty="dotted", lwd=2)
plot(agostomari.mpc, col=,add=TRUE)
par(lty="dashed", lwd=2)
plot(julhomari.mpc, col=,add=TRUE)
par(lty="dotdash", lwd=2)
plot(junhomari.mpc, col=,add=TRUE)
#second plot
par(bty="l", mar=c(0,1,0,1), oma=c(2,2,2,2),lty="solid", lwd=3, pty="m")
plot(area.total.mari.mpc)
par(lty="dotted", lwd=2)
plot(abrilmari.mpc, col=,add=TRUE)
par(lty="dashed", lwd=2)
plot(Dezmari.mpc, col=,add=TRUE)
par(lty="dotdash", lwd=2)
plot(outmari.mpc, col=,add=TRUE)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1) You're modifying `oma` (outer margin) after the first plot, which starts a new plot window.

2) `mar` and `mai` define the size of the plot margins in lines or inches respectively. You should define only one of them.

3) `plot(... add=T)` is similar to `lines(...)`

4) The `lty` can be set within the `plot`/`lines` call

```
# window settings
par(bty="l", mfrow=c(1,2), mar = c(0,1,0,1), oma = c(2,2,2,2))

#first plot
plot(area.total.mari.mpc, type='l', lwd = 3)
lines(agostomari.mpc, lty = 'dotted', lwd = 2)
lines(julhomari.mpc,  lty = 'dashed', lwd = 2)
lines(junhomari.mpc,  lty = 'dotdash', lwd = 2)

#second plot
plot(area.total.mari.mpc, type = 'l', lwd = 3)
lines(abrilmari.mpc, lty = 'dotted', lwd = 2)
lines(Dezmari.mpc, lty = 'dashed', lwd = 2)
lines(outmari.mpc, lty = 'dotdash', lwd = 2)
```